# Can't find error in my sum-of-squares code

Tags: python

```
def sum_of_squares(n):
  for i in range(1, n):
    for j in range(1, n):
      if n == i*i + j*j:
        return True
        break
      else:
        return False
```

Comment: seems like it, but why don't you try? Also `break` after `return` is useless. And for efficiency you could also loop until `sqrt(n)` only.

Comment: Why are you asking if it's correct? **Test it!**

Comment: No. It will return after testing `1*1 + 1*1`. Can you see why?

Comment: can't able to get this test cases  sumofsquares(10) and sumofsquares(11)

Comment: If you already know there is a bug in your code why don't you state it in your question? [ask]

Comment: Also, where do you define `true` and `false`? Do you mean `True` and `False`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient way would be to do it like that:

```
import math
def is_sum_of_squares(n):
    s=set()
    if 2*int(math.sqrt(n/2.0))**2==n:
        return True
    for i in range(1,int(math.sqrt(n)+1)):
        if n-i**2 in s:
            return True
        else:
            s.add(i**2)
    return False
```

Here you do only one iteration and only until the square root. The first `if` checks if `n` is a sum of two equal squares (like 8=4+4), as this case is not covered in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

you have to test for all values and not returning if the first try is not equal.

```
def sumofsquares(n):
  for i in range(1, n):
    for j in range(1, n):
      if n == (i*i) + (j*j):
        return (true)
  return (false)
```

you may also use pow:

```
pow(i, 2) + pow(j, 2)
```

or:

```
(i**2) + (j**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct because no matter what the n is, the function will will return after the first check. You should put the `return False` out of the two loops like:

```
def sumofsquares(n):
for i in range(1, n):
    for j in range(1, n):
        if n == ((i * i) + (j * j)):
            return True
return False
```

It would be better if j starts from i:

```
def sumofsquares(n):
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            if n == ((i * i) + (j * j)):
                return True
    return False
```